# ActiveRecord Unknown Attribute error (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

Where am I going wrong here? I get this error:

```
unknown attribute: bar_id
```

I have these two classes:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bazs
  has_many :foos
end
```

I'm getting this error when I try to create new Foos using:

```
 @bar = Bar.find(1)
 @bar.foos.create(:attribute1 => "a",
                  :attribute2 => "b")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example, you're not trying to create `Bars` but you're trying to create a `Foo` record that's associated to a `Bar` object. If you have a `belongs_to` association to `Bar` from `Foo`, then `Foo` needs to have a column called `bar_id` to reference which `Bar` a certain `Foo` record `belongs_to`.

Comment: Yes, I meant new Foos. I've updated the question appropriately. I thought having `belongs_to` and `has_many` in the right places would take care of the `bar_id` for me in my `foos` table. I added the `bar_id` and it worked! Thanks Leo.